# Make emacs aware of files externally moved/renamed on Mac os x

Tags: macos, emacs, file-management

I've been using mac os x for several years, and I realize that I've now gotten used to all applications transparently "following" files as I rename or move them (either via `mv` on the console or within the Finder's GUI), and emacs is pretty much the only program that does not.

This is a shame though, because most of my time in front a screen is actually spent in front of emacs :-)

Would anyone have any ideas or pointers about what measures I could take to get that behaviour in emacs ?

(yes I know this is "impossible" to acheive in general, but when I just rename a simple file, or move it to a directory nearby, it's a shame I have to close/reopen it for emacs to notice. oh and no, I'm not going to use *'dired'* as a file manager :-)

Comment: TextMate fails as well, surprisingly.

Comment: that's a real shame, as I suspect the file-following magic of mac os x is probably "only" implemented as some cocoa notification callback: "native" applications should all implement it, especially those who pretend to be programmer-oriented !

Comment: also, I realized that this question could also belong on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ but I'm not quite sure about what is the *right* way to cross-post a question.

Comment: Apple.SE is still in beta, and this site is just fine for your question -- we have several people haunting the `osx` tag. Maybe give it a few days, then you could try posting there.

Comment: asking the same question on IRC channel #emacs yielded thoughts about Cocoa implementing file access in a quite high-level manner (and in particular offering this file-following feature for free). I've never written any objective-C, nor do I know whether Textmate is implemented in o-C, but I now suppose that there is no hope to do any file-following on mac os x outside of Cocoa. Too bad for emacs !

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little different way to survice but my poor elisp would be useful to aware of editing old file.

```lisp
(defun my-prompt-saving-new-file ()
  "notify creating new file to avoid saving file moved externally."
  (interactive)
  (unless (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))
    (unless (y-or-n-p "Creating new file?")
      (keyboard-quit))))
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'my-prompt-saving-new-file)
```